# Dad, auntie, nana, grandpa, etc... What is this group of words used as informal family nicknames called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, kinship-terms, vocatives, hailnames

When explaining to someone learning French when one has to use *vous* (the “formal
you” pronoun) or *tu* (the “informal you” pronoun), there is a basic rule of thumb I
find useful:

> - ***Vous*** — Used when speaking to people you usually call by their last
>     name, title, or occupation.
>
>   for example: *Ms Smith, Sir, Doctor, Officer...*
> - ***Tu*** — Used when speaking to people you usually call by their first
>     name, nickname, or **[?** some word or phrase meaning informal/familiar family nickname
>     **?]**.
>
>   for example: *Georges, G-dog, Grandpa...*

I’m trying to find a word or short phrase to describe “family nicknames”
like *Dad, Nana*, etc., preferably one that doesn’t include the more formal
versions like *Father, Grandmother*, etc.

Comment: They're a particular subset of what's called _[Kinship terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=kinship+terms)_ in the trade.

Comment: [Sociolinguistic Perspectives : Papers on Language in Society, 1959-1994 ...
_ by Charles A. Ferguson Professor of Linguistics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=t3KdjmHsBgcC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=dad,+dada,+pop,+nanna,+mom,&source=bl&ots=OJkUB_-Ryp&sig=rig-T2C2Hd7DZ4OySddK_Ei9CPw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip--jQ4_rWAhXRyRoKHdLwBzAQ6AEIPDAH#v=onepage&q=dad%2C%20dada%2C%20pop%2C%20nanna%2C%20mom%2C&f=false) uses 'baby-talk words for [kin]'.

Comment: @JohnLawler Could you make it an answer? It may be the closest thing to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Informal terms for family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are [***kinship terms***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinship_terminology) (or *kinship words*).

This special class may overlap with what are known as *[terms of endearment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_endearment):* those words we use to address people for which we feel affection.

Answer (score -1):

Dad, being an **informal** word for “father”?
So the collective term you are looking for is “Informal Addresses” of Family Members?

Comment: Please add a source to support this term's usage.  Take a moment to [tour] the site and read the [FAQ] on how to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Mom, Dad, Nana, Opa, etc., are informal names for family members to be used when speaking to someone you know well (call by their first names).

Mother, Father, Grandmother, Grandfather, etc., are formal names for family members to be used when speaking to someone you know formally (call Mr./Ms. Last-Name).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nana

Edit:  Informal Familial Titles (*What is this group of words used as informal family nicknames called?*) as explained above.

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question which was after a single word to describe  “family nicknames”.

Comment: And OP has obviously considered the descriptor 'informal': they use it.

Comment: OP stated a word or short phrase to describe.

Answer (score -1):

**Relational Colloquialisms**

This is based on how we define & use the term 'colloquial' -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloquialism

Comment: This isn't an accepted term, not answering 'What is this set called?' Zero hits on Google: not even a loose collocation.

Answer (score -3):

terms of endearment (also includes sweetie-pie, cupcake, turtledove and the like)

Comment: I think that's not what is being asked. Mum, Dad, Nan, Pops are not 'terms of endearment'.

Comment: Terms of endearment not limited to enamorment, although many of the first examples you will see in dictionaries are of that nature. The term  however is broader in that it covers all those that endear us or are dear to us.

Comment: Also includes those phrases as in loving memory, loving father, beloved daughter etc on tombstones. (Although more accurately "endearments".)